# Multiple casbin policy RBAC and ABAC in model can not work at the same time

Tags: node.js, rbac, abac, casbin

I am trying to use the example of multiple casbin policy RBAC and ABAC.

Here are example model and policy from [official](https://github.com/casbin/casbin/tree/master/examples).

**[multiple_policy_definitions_model.conf](https://github.com/casbin/casbin/blob/master/examples/multiple_policy_definitions_model.conf)**

```
[request_definition]
r = sub, obj, act
r2 = sub, obj, act

[policy_definition]
p = sub, obj, act
p2= sub_rule, obj, act, eft

[role_definition]
g = _, _

[policy_effect]
e = some(where (p.eft == allow))

[matchers]
#RABC
m = g(r.sub, p.sub) && r.obj == p.obj && r.act == p.act
#ABAC
m2 = eval(p2.sub_rule) && r2.obj == p2.obj && r2.act == p2.act
```

**[multiple_policy_definitions_policy.csv](https://github.com/casbin/casbin/blob/master/examples/multiple_policy_definitions_policy.csv)**

```
p, data2_admin, data2, read
p2, r2.sub.Age > 18 && r2.sub.Age < 60, /data1, read, allow
p2, r2.sub.Age > 60 && r2.sub.Age < 100, /data1, read, deny

g, alice, data2_admin
```

My `request.query` is `{Age:20}`

```
...
const { query } = request;
const result = await e.enforce(query, '/data1', 'read');
console.log(result);
....
```

When running the above code, it's failing with this message：

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at D:\mandy\Project\e_shopping_api\node_modules\casbin\lib\cjs\util\builtinOperators.js:286:26
    at D:\mandy\Project\e_shopping_api\node_modules\expression-eval\dist\expression-eval.js:1:519
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.generatorRunAsync (D:\mandy\Project\e_shopping_api\node_modules\casbin\lib\cjs\util\util.js:160:26)
    at async Object.handler (D:\mandy\Project\e_shopping_api\src\routes\root.js:81:20)
```

I guess it does not use `r2,p2,e,m2` to match.

I also try it on [Casbin online editor](https://casbin.org/editor/)

When I use Request `r2,p2,e,m2` it work.

But I don't know how to implement by using `e.enforce()`.

[Casbin online editor r2,p2,m2 work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzwgJ.png)

[Casbin online editor r,p,m work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0jPW.png)

I much appreciate any responses.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear but you should look into [tag:alfa] or Cedar as an alternative. They're easier to understand as languages.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I would take a try.